# AngularJS simple test not working?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to follow the tutorial using notepad and Chrome, here's the code I have but it comes up with the error

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'testhere' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/ng/areq?p0=testhere&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

Any idea what on earth I'm missing here?  I'm sure it's trivial and daft but can't find it for the life of me!

```
<html ng-app>
    <head>
        <script>
        function testhere($scope)
        {
            $scope.totalcount=4;
        }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="testhere">
            {{totalcount}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using Angular 1.3, that means you need to create a module and attach the controller to it: `angular.module("myApp", []).controller("testhere", function () { ... } );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Angular 1.3.x you cant define global controllers by defualt

there are two ways

**1) register controllers with .controller()**

First make an module by providing name of module in first argument and dependencies in second(there are no dependencies for now)

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
```

use .controller()

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.controller('testhere'.function CommentsCtrl($scope) {
       ...
    })
```

**2) or set global controller option**

```
angular.module('myModule',[])
.config(['$controllerProvider', function($controllerProvider) {
  $controllerProvider.allowGlobals();
}]);
```

in html

```
<html ng-app="myModule">
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through this  [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/tuwatixaji/3/edit)   comment the required version of angular and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Please see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller to see how to define a controller in Angular. Your testthere now is just a function in javascript, not a controller

And also, your application javascript (controller, etc) should be after angular library in the head section